# Delete all images from folder except a original image in php

Tags: php, image

I want delete all images from 'Logo' folder except an original image.

eg.

```
demo.jpg - original image

demo_50.jpg, demo_100.jpg, demo_150.jpg - other images.
```

Now i want to delete all images except demo.jpg using php

Comment: so how is your code doing?

Comment: i know about delete a single image using unlink(). i dont know about how to delete files from a specified folder except original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a list of file which you do not want to delete in a directory.

```
$dir = 'direcotry';
$keepFiles = array('demo.jpg');

foreach( glob("$dir/*") as $file ) {
    if( !in_array(basename($file), $keepFiles) )
        unlink($file);
}
```

Another solution to this is,

1.Move that original file from current directory say X to some other directory say Y

2.Remove the complete directory X

3.Now move back that original file from Y to X

Comment: can you help for my another issue.?

Comment: Error occurs during image uploading with german named image like (Logo_FC_Bayern_München). How to solve it.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['document']["tmp_name"][$i],$clientFileUploadPath.$_FILES['document']["name"][$i]);

Comment: $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'] contains the uploaded file path.
if you are uploading multiple file with array structure then only you need to use $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'][$i]
Another thing make sure the directory in which you are moving files have proper permissions

Comment: i solved that issue using utf8_decode(). But this only works on local machine not in the live. can u help me? i also reached the maximum question limit in this site. please try to help mate.

Comment: can you please check the file permission in which you are moving uploaded files and also add your form code

Comment: i also gave 0777 permission. And files uploading is works fine. but a file name containing the special characters is not uploaded.

Comment: You can check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838994/replace-special-characters-before-the-file-is-uploaded-using-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444031/browser-could-not-read-filename-which-contains-special-characters

Comment: thanks for your suggestion mate. Very thank you for giving great time with me.

Answer (score 0):

use `unlink`:

```
 if( !in_array($file, $original) )//$file is total file in the directory
        unlink($file);
```

see this post also:[delete image from folder PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005899/delete-image-from-folder-php)